# Can I access Windows OS from my now-secondary storage?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, multi-boot

I had Windows on the primary HDD storage of my laptop, which I dual-booted with Ubuntu and now I had two OS on that HDD.

Recently I bought an SSD, made it my primary storage, and installed Ubuntu on it. For this, I made my HDD as secondary storage that I attached on my laptop by replacing the CD Drive.

Now I am unable to access/open neither the Windows OS nor the former Ubuntu from the grub of this new OS on this SSD. The HDD storage of both OS can be accessed, though.

How can I get access to Windows? Any help or suggestion is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Try to be more precise: "The HDD storage of both OS can be accessed". What should that be? When quoting Windows, mention the version number. When talking about your drives, please detail drive layout in terms of partitions, volumes and file systems used. The partition table mode, MBR or GPT might as well play a role.
Furthermore, Grub is supposed to start and load operating systems and is not a replacement for full disk access when running an operating system.
Encryption could be an issue as well.

Comment: From the file manager of my SSD Operating System (Ubuntu), I can access the FILES on the now-secondary storage of my laptop, much like an external hard drive you can say. I'm not sure how to give partition details though. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 were the OS that I had on the now-secondary storage which was formerly my primary storage before I bought the SSD.

Comment: If you can access the files the problems seems to be solved. You can use fdisk to list your partitions: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/fdisk/
A sentence like "The HDD storage of both OS can be accessed, though." is incomprehensible.

Comment: @r2d3 I can read the files as of now, but I want to boot the system on the Windows OS that is present on my secondary storage.